# Combine a string-array with the remove- and split-function, to only one line of code?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can this piece of code be shorten to only one line of code?

```
string[] result1 = content.Split('|');
string result2 = result1[1].Remove(0, 4);
```

Seriously sorry, but I'm at a loss right now.

Comment: Just join both lines: string result2 = content.Split('|')[1].Remove(0, 4);

Comment: Why do you *want* to only use a single line of code? (And do you still need both variables?) More context is definitely required here.

Comment: Jamming multiple logical steps into one line of code makes the code harder to read, debug and maintain.  It doesn't run any faster and it is the mark of an amateur

Comment: And to what Steve said, you should add that, in this specific case, the reliability is potentially lower: `string[] result1 = content.Split('|');
string result2 = ""; if(result1.Length > 1) result2 = result1[1].Remove(0, 4);` Works always. The summarised version you are asking for crashes if `|` is not present in `content`. Reducing the length of the code can be good in some contexts, but not always.

Comment: i know, but i got stuck in my code, since I'm sitting here programming for hours. Could not remember how to solve it. Joining both lines together is propably what i needed and other information is not necessary. So, I assume combining those two lines of code will not inconvenience myself :-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to **complete array back with first item modified**.

```
string[] result = content.Split('|').Select((r, i) => 
                        new { Value = i == 0 ? r.Remove(0, 4) : r, Index = i })
                        .Select(r => r.Value)
                        .ToArray();
```

Comment: I know, it's not actually what I asked for, but I like this expression better. This keeps my array original, with small modifications. I adjusted accordingly the value from 0 to 1, because it is the second placeholder i need to modify. thank you

Comment: @MrMAG, Somehow I read `var result` instead of `string result` and I assumed that you needed a modified array. That is why I posted it. But consider Jon Skeet comment, having it on a single line doesn't improve readability

Answer (score 3):

```
string result2 = content.Split('|')[1].Remove(0, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this by joining both the lines like this:-

```
string result2 = content.Split('|')[1].Remove(0, 4);
```

Although as Jon Skeet mentioned in the comments it looks very logical question as to why you want to do this? As it is highly recommended to write a readable code.

Answer (score 3):

a different answer  try  it

```
 public static class MyExtensions
   {
     public static string SplitRemove(this String str,int arrayIndex,int charToRemove)
     {
        return str.Split(new char[] { '|' },
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)   [arrayIndex].Remove(0,charToRemove);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok you  write it once and  whenever you call it you have one line of code

Answer (score 1):

```
string result2 = content.Split('|')[1].Remove(0, 4);
```

Comment: This is a question about C#.